# jQuery, focus-handler doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I've tried to create a very simple test with .focus(), for alerting me when it's set:
http://jsfiddle.net/hensor/h892gf4e/

```
<a href="#">Item 1</a>
<a href="#">Item 2</a>
<a href="#">Item 3</a>
```

```js
$('a').first().focus(function() {
    alert('Focus on item 1');
});
```

But it never calls the alert. Wonder why.

Comment: when do you want the event to be fired

Comment: Your fiddle appears to be working fine here. Note that you will be stuck in an `alert()` loop, because when you click the `a` element an `alert` will show. When you clear the `alert`, the `a` will be given focus again, so another `alert` will appear, and so on. You would be best to change the `alert()` to `console.log()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works.

However if you want to trigger it on page load, you need to bind event first, then trigger it.

```
$('a').focus(function () {
    alert('Focus on item 1');
}).first().focus();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mvcmwmdv/)

Comment: This is what I needed, sorry for the unclear question. I want to take focus on page load and then to stuff.